# Premature Deletion of Comments – [Resolved]

Tags: discussion, comments, meta

I'm not very comfortable with being told I can't comment on Meta posts.

The whole idea of Meta is to give the community a say, or an opportunity to give feedback on new initiatives and changes.

Why then are my reasonable comments being deleted less than 12 hours after I wrote them?

It doesn't allow for discussion, or for people to share their thoughts.

To have comments deleted without even being consulted, when they weren't rude or obsolete, is very discouraging.

What is with the new policy of don't comment on some Meta posts?

Comment: I apologize for how I acted, its been a long and stressful week for me. I don't really agree with your idea and flagged it obsolete. I do feel like I have that right as IMO all users do even on meta. I've never declined an obsolete flag if its by the person who owns the Q or A. I could've handled it better in this case though and at least left you a comment. I've put your idea back and done just that.

Comment: And for the record I didn't downvote this, I never downvote any questions in Meta... rarely downvote answers in meta.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you had a rough week.  I didn't intend to make it harder with my original comment. I've had comments removed before with no issue, I felt I had to speak up on this occasion because my comment was intended only to help, and if I can't post it on Meta, and I don't have time for chat, then I have nowhere to voice my input. It's resolved now so no hard feelings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mods discussed this internally, going forward we will be more mindful of how comments are handled in meta.

Comment: He means me! :( sorry I'm such a blunt jerk most of the time.